# Given a positive integer $n$, some straight lines and lattice points such... Prove that the number of the lines is at least $n(n+3)$.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, alternative-proof, algebraic-combinatorics

> Given a positive integer $n$ and some straight lines in the plane
> such that none of the lines passes through $(0,0)$, and such that every lattice point
> $(a,b)$, where $ 0\leq a,b\leq n$ are integers and $a+b>0$, is contained
> by at least $a+b+1$ of the lines. Prove that the number of the lines is at
> least $n(n+3)$.

**Solution:** Let us count the number of pairs $({\bf line},{\bf point})$ on two ways.

- Say we have $l$ lines and each can pass at most $n+1$ points. Say $k$ of them pass through $n+1$ points, then $k\leq 2n+1$. So all of them pass at most through $$k(n+1)+n(l-k) \leq (l+2)n+1$$ points, so we have at most $(l+2)n+1$ pairs $({\bf line},{\bf point})$.
- On the other hand all points pass at least thorugh $$\sum_{a=0}^n\sum_{b=0}^n (a+b+1)-1 = n^3+3n^2+3n  $$ lines, so we have at list that many pairs $({\bf line},{\bf point})$.
- So we have $$n^3+3n^2+3n\leq (l+2)n+1\implies l\geq n(n+3)$$
  and thus a conclusion.

Is there a polynomial aproach to this problem? (Like defining some polynomials which wanish on some set of points...)

Comment: Minor mistake in your proof: The constraint on $k$ should be $k \le 2n \color{red}{+1}$, as you forgot to count the diagonal line from $(0,n)$ to $(n,0)$ which passes through $n+1$ lattice points.  Using this correct constraint you will conclude $l \ge n(n+3)$ as stated, instead of $l \ge n(n+3) \color{red}{+ 1}$.

Comment: You can further strengthen the result using your approach. Since each line that doesn't pass through $n+1$ points, will pass through at most $ \frac{ n+1}{2}$ points, we actually have # (line, poin) $ \leq k (n+1) +  \frac{n+1}{2} ( l - k ) \leq l(\frac{n+1}{2} ) + (2n+1)(\frac{n+1}{2} ) $.  This gives us $ l \geq 2n^2 + 2n $. (We could improve this bound slightly by counting the number of lines that pass through $ \approx \frac{n+1}{2}$ points $k_1$, and bounding the term even more.)

Comment: @CalvinLin - but a line can pass through $n$ points if it is parallel to a diagonal.

Comment: Good point. Accounting for these $~2n$ diagonal lines of slope $\pm 1$ that pass through $\geq n/2$ points, we have #(line, point) $ <  l (n+1)/2 + (4n+1) ( n+1)/2 ) $ and so $ l  > 2n^2 $, which is still much stronger than the initial result. (Some approximation because I didn't track the exact values)

Comment: 1)  If we do not require that the lines are unique (which wasn't stated in the question), then the bound is sharp. This construction is given by Fedor's first paragraph, and his proof uses Combinaotrial Nullstenstaz which allows for repeated lines (which is how I would have approached it). 2) If we do not allow for repeated lines (which might be a reasonable assumption - note that I assumed that the lines were distinct in my comments), then the bound is very weak, and we need $\Omega(n^{5/2})$ distinct lines. (I believe your work here shows $ n > 2n^2 \pm \epsilon$)

Comment: But what does it mean line is not unique? @CalvinLin Why would we count the same line more than once?

Comment: How is it that an answer was posted (on 30 September 2020), awarded a bounty, and then deleted by its author? Someone playing games here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are alebraic proofs for a general statement, but in 2-dimension they are more involving than the elementary ways. (In higher dimension I know only algebraic methods.) I would not call it linear algebra; it is much closer to Hermite interpolation and divided differences.

The origin of this problem family is a paper of Alon and Füredi, [Covering the Cube by Affine Hyperplanes](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/Publications/Covering%20the%20cube%20by%20affine%20hyperplanes.pdf). The most popular variant is [IMO problem 2007/6](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h159989p894658). I asked this multi-set variant in the KöMaL contest, [Problem A. 510. in 2010](https://www.komal.hu/feladat?a=feladat&f=A510&l=en).
A set of more general statements can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.2901.pdf); the current question is a particular case of Theorem 12.

---

Instead of remaking a full proof, let me give you an outline only. The main idea is that we define a polynomial $P(x,y)$ that is the product of equations of the lines. This polynomial satisfies
$P(0,0)\ne0$ and $\frac{\partial^i}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial^j}{\partial x^j}P(a,b)=0$ whenever $0\le a,b\le n$, $a+b>0$ and $i+j\le a+b$. Already these
properties imply that $\deg P\ge n(n+3)$.

$\textbf{Lemma 1d:}$ There is a unique set of real numbers $c_{i,j}$ ($0\le j\le i\le n$) with the following property: for every polynomial $p(x)=a_0+\ldots+a_{n(n+3)/2}x^{n(n+3)/2}$ we have $a_{n(n+3)/2}=\sum_{0\le j\le i} p^{(i)}(j)$. Moreover, $c_{0,0}\ne0$.

A possible proof is expanding the Taylor coefficient / divided difference
$$ a_{n(n+3)/2} = f[0,1,1,2,2,2,\ldots,\underbrace{n,\ldots,n}_{n+1}] = \sum_{0\le j\le i\le n}c_{i,j}f^{(j)}(i).$$
It is easy to compute the coefficients $c_{i,i}$ (with $i=j$) explicitly; in particular, $c_{0,0}=\frac{1}{(-1)^2(-2)^3\cdots(-n)^{n+1}}$.

$\textbf{Lemma 2d:}$ Suppose that $p(x,y)=\sum a_{u,v}x^uy^v$ is a polynomial with degree at most $n(n+3)$. Then the coefficient of $(xy)^{n(n+3)/2}$ in $p$ is
$$ a_{n(n+3)/2,n(n+3)/2} = \sum_{0\le j\le i\le n}\sum_{0\le k\le l\le n} c_{i,j}c_{k,\ell}  \frac{\partial^{j+\ell}}{\partial x^j\partial y^\ell} p(i,k). $$

Proof: Just apply Lemma 1d to each monomial in $p$.

$\textbf{Corollary:}$ $\deg P\ge n(n+3)$, so the number of lines is at least $\deg P\ge n(n+3)$.

Proof: By Lemma 2d, the coefficient of $(xy)^{n(n+3)/2}$ in $P(x,y)$ is nonzero.

Comment: Finnaly! This is really great. Thanks! Do you think this can be also done with polynomial method:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164782/suppose-we-have-n-points-in-a-plane-not-all-on-the-same-line-then-they-are-d

Comment: This articles you send are also splendid!